# Recursively iterate over decreasing list

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I want to recursively iterate over a list without considering the items i'm deleting

Code:

```
list_example = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '(', 'a', 'a', ')']
for index, item in enumerate(list_example):
    if item == 'a':
        del list_example[index]
```

Now the removal works but the for loop doesn't know that the items are deleted, how do i make it so that the updated list is considered every time?

Comment: Use a while loop instead of a for loop and maintain your own index

Comment: What is "recursive iteration"? I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: If your problem is with the index, you could just shift the index by 1 every time you delete an element

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the issue you've encountered is to iterate over the list in reverse. That way, the current index is independent of deletions for elements with greater indices.

```py
list_example = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '(', 'a', 'a', ')']
for index in reversed(range(len(list_example))):
    if list_example[index] == 'a':
        del list_example[index]
```

Another way to remove elements, if you don't need to modify the list in-place, is to use a list comprehension combined with a condition (`if x != 'a'`).

```py
list_example = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '(', 'a', 'a', ')']
list_example = [x for x in list_example if x != 'a']
```

Additionally, Python has a `filter` function, which takes a function for specifying elements to drop.

```py
list_example = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '(', 'a', 'a', ')']
list_example = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'a', list_example))
```

Comment: `reversed(range(len(list_example)))` might be a bit more readable than `range(len(list_example) - 1, -1, -1)` ?

Comment: @fountainhead, I agree and have updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to remove elements, if you **do** need to modify the list in-place, is to use: `list_example[:] = [x for x in list_example if x!= 'a']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_example = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '(', 'a', 'a', ')']
for item in reversed(list_example):
    if (item == 'a'):               # Found an 'a' while going right-to-left
        list_example.remove('a')    # Remove the first 'a' going from left-to-right
print (list_example)
```

**Output:**

```
['(', ')']
```